# Parentheses in Haskell: where/why are they forbidden on LHS of a decl

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm used to parentheses in Haskell being mostly optional: they're needed to override the usual binding/precedence; otherwise freely add/omit them to aid readability. Then consider these (at GHC 8.6.5.):

```
f (Just x) = x         -- needed around `(Just x)` because `f Just x` would bind differently

(Just y)   = Just ()   -- pattern based binding for var `y`
Just y2    = Just ()   -- but optional around `(Just y)`
Just (y3)  = Just ()   -- optional around bare variables
x          = ()
(x2)       = ()
```

Without trying it first, do you expect parens would be optional around the LHS of a function equation here:

```
(f (Just x)) = x
```

That's rejected: `Parse error in pattern: f`. "in pattern" suggests that the parser expects `(` to start a pattern, then why isn't the pattern `Just y2 = ...` rejected because no parens?

Something inconsistent/a little weirder happens with

```
{-# LANGUAGE  PatternSynonyms    #-}

pattern MkJust x = Just x        -- OK
-- pattern M2Just (x) = Just x   -- parse error on input `('
-- pattern (M3Just x) = Just x   -- parse error on input `M3Just'
```

Is there some rationale/logic/(um) pattern to the parens with these examples?

I'm asking because I always write patterns in parens `(Just y) = ...`; I was surprised the parens were optional because `Just y2 = ...` could easily be a typo for a function decl `just y2 = ...`.

**Addit:** Ah yes, parens are required around an operator used prefix. These work:

```
pattern (::~~) x y = (x, y)        -- OK
pattern x ::~ y    = (x, y)        -- OK

(::~~) True y4     = (True, ())    -- OK
(True ::~~  y5)    = (True, ())    -- OK
True ::~~  y6      = (True, ())    -- OK
```

This doesn't

```
-- pattern (x ::~~ y) = (x, y)  -- parse error on input `x'
```

Comment: Have you checked the [syntax reference](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html)?

Comment: I'm not claiming there's any illegal syntax here. I'm asking what the logic is. The H2010 Report is so far behind GHC, I don't think the reference is much help. AFAICT it's all allowed by the Report; also Hugs behaves the same. The `pattern` synonym stuff is of course an extension.

Comment: This might have been intentional, or an oversight from the syntax designers. It's hard to answer questions of the form "why this was designed in this way, when alternatives exist?", especially when the issue is a very minor one like this. I fear only someone who designed the language can answer such questions.

Comment: Just because `(` is expected to start a pattern, doesn't mean that a pattern has to start with `(` to answer the first question.

Comment: This is a question not for the SO but to the GHC gitlab I think